# android app install attempt fails with: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]

Tags: android

Trying to install my app into an emulator that is based on Android 4.3 (API 18) and get "INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK".  I had to compile the app, via ant, using SDK Build Tools 18.1.1 because 19 was failing with an error referring to something about "nio". In poking around the web, found that 19 and 22 may be "hosed" so I went with the suggested 18.1.1.

My AndroidManifest file has:
`minSDKVersion="18"`
`targetSdkVersion="18.1.1."`

My project.properties file has:
`target=android-18`
`sdk.buildtools=18.1.1`

I don't have a lot of choice in creating the emulator - I have to go with API 19 or 18.  I went with API 18 because I compiled with SDK buildtools 18.1.1.  (Note I am working on Linux and am not using eclipse.)  Clearly missing something basic here. Do I need to build an emulator based on 18.1.1 to match the SDK Build Tools I used to compile?  Is that even possible? Are either the manifest or project.properties files wrong?  Any advice on how to get around this app install error is welcome.

TIA,
Steve

Answer (score 1):

As Android says in  :

> android:targetSdkVersion
>   An integer designating the API Level that the application targets. If not set, the default value equals that given to minSdkVersion.

Just put a version equal or higher that your minSdkVersion. You should do for example : `targetSdkVersion="18"`

But you should bring an integer.

And for the targetSdkVersion, what you need is only to install the given version in your Android SDK Manager.

Comment: Thanks "gahfy"!  That indeed fixed my problem.  Do you know anything about Android hopefully fixing the issues with versions 19 (and possibly 22 although I haven't tried compiling with this version yet).  As mentioned, I had an error relating to "nio" when I tried to compile with 19.

Comment: API 19 of Android SDK is the version KitKat. So, there is no version 22. What is your problem with "nio" ? Maybe needs an other question with detailed logcat in it and what you've put in your code.

Comment: How can I capture compile errors in logcat?  Started logcat up, but when I do "ant debug" the errors don't show in logcat.
       [dx] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
       [dx] java.nio.BufferOverflowException

Comment: sorry, hit return on the comment above by accident!

Comment: dang, I've got to stay away from the return key!  this is part of the error, 
       [dx] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
       [dx] java.nio.BufferOverflowException
       [dx]     at java.nio.Buffer.nextPutIndex(Buffer.java:519)
       [dx]     at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.putShort(HeapByteBuffer.java:315)
       [dx]     at com.android.dex.Dex$Section.writeShort.  As asked above, how to capture compile errors in logcat?  Note I used API-19 for this compile.  This is code from one of the earlier sections of the Google Android tutorial.